# how can i add a css file to body of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a page which has a print view so when the user clicks on "Print" a new window pops up and I want to add a .css file just for that window.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you just include that CSS file in the header of the resulting preview page? Without showing us any code, what you've tried, or even asking us a question at all - it's pretty impossible to know how to help you.

Comment: Is your new window a separate URL or content on your page that's opened in a new window?

Comment: I am trying something like this   $(document).ready(function() {
               $(".print").click(function(){
          $("link").attr("href", "css/ecsPrint.css");
         return false;
       });
       });

Comment: @Adam Yes it opens in a new window

Comment: You didn't really answer my question.. is it a 1) New URL, or 2) content on your page.  I assumed you're asking #2, in which case see my answer below.

Comment: Is it enough to only use the stylesheet when printing? Will be visible in the standard print preview or do you want to show a popup with the new stylesheet applied?

Comment: @Adam its the same URL with the some modifications as per the new css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".print").click(function () {
        $("head").append("<link>");
        css = $("head").children(":last");
        css.attr({
            rel: "stylesheet",
            type: "text/css",
            href: "css/ecsPrint.css"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Unless this is a Internal Web Application, i wouldnt recommend loading css with JS.

Comment: "Unless this is a corporate site" lol.  As someone who writes "corporate" sites in addition to external ones, I declare this hilarious, but bad for my heart.

Comment: is that more to your liking adam ?

Comment: I'm being a proponent of web best practices regardless of the environment.  I prefer "I wouldn't recommend loading CSS with JS. Period.  It can be wonky and unclear."

Comment: You are right adam, i am not a native english speaker ( or writer for this case ), and i try to minimize my answers to what i can write :\ but you are right, "I wouldnt recommend loading CSS with JS" is the right comment.

Comment: For what it's worth, I couldn't tell that your English was anything but fluent.  Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

When including your stylesheet, use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: This is how you specify a stylesheet to only apply when printing.

Comment: I don't think this is what he's asking...?  He seems to want to load content into a new window and then style it visually to the user.  This won't be visible on screen--only when printing.

Comment: Totally not your fault at all. :)

Comment: And I didn't mean to offend you in any way ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can add a print only style sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  media="print" href="print.css" />
```

This stylesheet does not need to be "added" to popup windows. It will be ignored when the user is in the "normal" view and then only applied when the user goes to print the document.

If you want to be both visible and apply to the printed document, just have it cascade.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="normal.css" /> #normal styling
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="print.css" /> #override normal styling
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  media="print" href="print.css" /> #override normal, for printer
```

That way you get the best of both worlds. Override the css rules in `normal.css` with new rules in `print.css`, as needed to make the document look as you wish. The new document will visually look different and then also print out differently.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Removed due to clarification.  New answer:

Open the URL in a new window as such: `blah.aspx?print=true`

Then on your backend:

```
//Assuming you use .NET...
if(Request.Querystring("print").toLower() == "true" ) { //Convert to bool type if you are so inclined
   printCSS.Visible = True;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." visible="false" runat="server" id="printCSS" />
</head>
```

You could also use one of the jQuery methods shown to load it in using jQuery too.

Comment: actually I am loading the same page in print view with some changes as per the css file.

Comment: I recommend, in that case, using a URL querystring param that your jQuery or back-end code looks at and then loads the appropriate CSS file directly into the head.